# <input> value lost on keyup / .innerHTML call

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm working on a project which imitates a console window. When the user presses enter, a new `<input>` text field is added to the screen and focused upon. The only problem is that the values of the previous `<input>` fields are lost in the process.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="console_window"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
var input;

function init() {

    function keyup(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 13:
                document.body.innerHTML += 
                    "<input type='text' class='console_window'/>"  

                input = document.getElementsByClassName("console_window")[document.getElementsByClassName("console_window").length-1]; 

                input.focus();

                break;
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyup, false);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

And the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpa6d9bf/).
Also, I prefer not to use plugins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because your are reseting the page's html markup...

Instead of addind pure HTML text, you should consider using DOM elements manipulation:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpa6d9bf/1/)

```
var inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.className = "console_window";
inp.type = "text";

document.body.appendChild(inp);
inp.focus();
```

Comment: Good answer, very precise and very little code needed.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `document.body.innerHTML += "<input type='text' class='console_window'/>"`, you are destroying all the input elements and recreating them. When you do this, the values do not copy over. You want to use something like appendChild to add the new input element to the DOM.

Comment: We're here to offer help and advice. I explained the problem in enough detail to lead you to a solution. Forcing you to do a little more research on your own is going to do more for you than giving you the answer outright

Comment: Yes, I agree, and your answer was very helpful, but the answer that I chose also gave me a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/894yo3ja/

```
var input;

function keyup(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 13:
            var i = document.getElementsByClassName("console_window").length + 1;
            document.getElementById(i - 1).setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(i - 1).value);
            document.body.innerHTML += "<input type='text' class='console_window' id='" + i + "'/>";
            document.getElementById(i).focus();
            break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", keyup, false);
```

Hope that helps, the value doesn't get stored, so you have to set the value attribute.

The issue you have is that when you re write the inner html out, the value that you have entered into the input is wiped out. To actually set the value to the input before overwriting the inner html on the body you would need to call .setAttribute("value",value); on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's not very code efficient though, and no explanation.

Comment: @user3412847 Thanks for the comment, updated my answer to explain the changes that I made.